# ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels' in python3.5.2

Tags: python, python-3.5, statsmodels

When I do import statsmodels i get the following error -

```
ImportError: No module named 'statsmodels'
```

I try to install it using `pip install statsmodels` but I get Requirement already satisfied

Also when i do this - `python -mpip install statsmodels`
I get -

```
ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'
```

I have 2.7 and 3.5 installed, however I use only 3.5. 
Also I did pip3 list and I am getting statsmodels(0.6.1) in the list of installed packages

Also when I am using the console to connect to python I am getting the same error -  ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'

Comment: you're getting this error when you do `import statsmodels` ?

Comment: Do you have multiple python Version installed? Try following command `py -3.5 -m pip list` to Show installed packages or to install `py -3.5 -m pip install statsmodels`

Comment: I have 2.7 and 3.5 installed, however I use only 3.5. Also I did pip3 list and I am getting statsmodels(0.6.1) in the list of installed packages

Comment: When I did python3.5 -m pip install statsmodels I got an error - ImportError: No module named '_sysconfigdata_m'

Comment: This isn't by any chance happening to you in Azure ML Workbench, is it?

Comment: Please edit your question to indicate by what means you are running the script where you are importing statsmodels.  That information is necessary to diagnose the problem.  It sounds like you're implying that you are using the terminal.